# Moving my source from one machine to another machine in vue-cli3

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js, configuration, vue-cli-3

I have my source files in my local system, i want to move all my codes to a same setup in my server. Is there a way to do this other than creating all the files manually and copy/pasting the code from my local to server.

I am using vue.js, vue-cli and GIT.

Please help

Comment: bro thats why you had created ``package.json``

Comment: Sorry bro, i am really new to this vue.js. Is there any steps to follow ? or links which i can take a look at ?

Comment: yeah bro it will work till all packages were installed in machine same like its were in previous machine.

Comment: Bro i get it, there were many .vue files, .js files and package.json file in the project. All i am asking is that in the new environment do i have to manually create all the files in those names as copy the code in the local system into the server or is there a way to export and import the same in vue-cli.

Comment: Ok how many package.json file you had

Comment: only one package.json file

Comment: then whats makes you worry?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197878/discussion-between-mani079-and-krishna-kamal).

Comment: You can push your repo to a git remote, so you could setup a remote on the server

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to copy your source Vue project directory to the new server without the `node_modules` folder.  You can do this from the terminal of the source server like so:

```
rsync -r --exclude node_modules/ /root/my_vue_project/ root@mynewmachine.com:/root/my_vue_project
```

Second you need to install the dependencies.  To do this you'll need to run `npm install` from the project directory on the new machine:

```
cd /root/my_vue_project;npm install
```

That's it.  Now you can test to make sure it works:

```
cd /root/my_vue_project;npx vue-cli-service serve --mode development --host 0.0.0.0
```

It goes without saying that node.js, npm, and Vue should already be installed on the new machine.